# What does Islam say about being brave?

Tags: sunni

I have so many fears in life. I'm always scared of something. I know I should only fear Allah and rely upon Him and I should believe in predestination. I want to know how can a person let his fears go away and just fear Allah. I also wanted to know is this saying true according to Islam "Luck favors the brave.". I know the example of Khalid Bin Waleed r.a is great when comes to bravery.

Comment: i think its vast topic ,so you should break down into 2 or 3 parts/ because fear from ALLAH means ***Taqwa*** ,so for description its too extensive topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Braveness is certainly recommended and highly appreciated in Islam you may find a lot's of ahadith on this (and related) topic(s):

> Narrated Anas:
>
> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) was the (most handsome), most generous and the bravest of all the people. Once the people of Medina got frightened having heard an uproar at 
>   night. So, the Prophet (ﷺ) met the people while he was riding an unsaddled horse belonging to Abu Talha and carrying his sword (slung over his shoulder). He said (to

them), "Don't get scared, don't get scared." Then he added, "I found it (i.e the horse) very fast." (https://sunnah.com/bukhari/56/246)

So braveness was one of our prophet's attributes.

> It was narrated from Zaid bin Zibyan, and attributed to Abu Dharr, that the Prophet said:
>
> "There are three whom Allah, the Mighty and Sublime, loves, and three whom Allah, the Mighty and Sublime, hates. As for those whom Allah, the Mighty and Sublime, 
>   loves: A man who comes to some people and asks (to be given something) for the sake of Allah, the Mighty and Sublime, and not for the sake of their relationship, but 
>   they do not give him. So one man stayed behind and gave to him in secret, and no one knew of his giving except Allah, the Mighty and Sublime, and the one to whom he 
>   gave it. People who travel all night until sleep becomes dearer to them than anything that may be equivalent to it, so they lay down their heads (and slept). Then a 
>   man among them got up and started praying to Me and beseeching Me, reciting MY Ayat. **And a man who was on a campaign and met the enemy and they fled, but he went 
>   forward (pursuing them) until he was killed or Allah, the Mighty and Sublime, granted victory to him**. And three whom Allah hates are the old man who commits Zina, 
>   the poor man who shows off, and the rich man who is unjust."
>    (https://sunnah.com/urn/1125790)

This hadith is used to show force and braveness against enemies,

> Abu Huraira reported Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) as saying:
>
> A strong believer is better and is more lovable to Allah than a weak believer, and there is good in everyone, (but) cherish that which gives you benefit (in the 
>   Hereafter) and seek help from Allah and do not lose heart, and if anything (in the form of trouble) comes to you, don't say: If I had not done that, it would not have 
>   happened so and so, but say: Allah did that what He had ordained to do and your" if" opens the (gate) for the Satan. (https://sunnah.com/muslim/46/52)

This hadith should relief everybody a bit as it shows that being strong and brave is not given to all people and therefore it is not haram to be weak or fearful.

> Narrated Anas bin Malik:
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) used to say, "O Allah! I seek refuge with You from worry and grief, from incapacity and laziness, from cowardice and miserliness, from being heavily in 
>   debt and from being overpowered by (other) men." (See Hadith No. 374) (https://sunnah.com/bukhari/80/66)

So our prophet used to seek refuge from cowardice. Which means that it is a rather disliked attitude.

> It is narrated on the authority of Tariq b. Shihab:
>
> It was Marwan who initiated (the practice) of delivering khutbah (address) before the prayer on the 'Id day. A man stood up and said: Prayer should precede khutbah. He 
>   (Marwan) remarked, This (practice) has been done away with. Upon this Abu Sa'id remarked: This man has performed (his duty) laid on him. I heard the Messenger of Allah 
>   as saying: He who amongst you sees something abominable should modify it with the help of his hand; and if he has not strength enough to do it, then he should do it 
>   with his tongue, and if he has not strength enough to do it, (even) then he should (abhor it) from his heart, and that is the least of faith. 
>   (https://sunnah.com/muslim/1/84)

This hadith shows that braveness is necessary as one may need to raise his voice gaiant abominable things if one see them while just rejecting them in the heart is a 
sign of a rather weak faith.

And in the qur'an Allah also  wants us Muslims to be strong and brave:

> And prepare against them whatever you are able of power and of steeds of war by which you may terrify the enemy of Allah and your enemy and others besides them whom 
>   you do not know [but] whom Allah knows. And whatever you spend in the cause of Allah will be fully repaid to you, and you will not be wronged. (8:60 
>   https://quranx.com/8.60)

This verse shows that Muslims should show power and strength to their enemies instead of being fearful or weak.

And

> If you do not go forth, He will punish you with a painful punishment and will replace you with another people, and you will not harm Him at all. And Allah is over 
>   all things competent. (9:39 https://quranx.com/9.39)

Those who are not have been be warned by this verse.

Answer (score -1):

***the skins of those who fear their Lord shiver from it (when they recite it or hear it). Then their skin and their heart soften to the remembrance of Allah."*** [39:23]

Taqwa means consciousness, awe or fear of Allah, which inspires a person to be on guard against wrong action and eager for actions which please Allah and stay away from those actions which displease and anger him.

***Ghazali (rahmatullahi `alayhi) said***: ‘Fear rips away desires and muddens luxuries so that cherished sins become reprehensible, just as a honey lover is repelled by it when he learns that it has poison in it. This is how fear burns desires; disciplines the organs; subordinates the heart and gives it tranquility. It also enables the heart to rid itself of pride, hatred, and envy; and it leaves it absorbed in it (fear). Hence, the heart becomes preoccupied with its own worries and looks towards its best interest in the long run. It is then engaged in only matters like meditation, self-analysis and struggle. It cherishes its time and moments.’ [Ihya: 4/160]

1.Always be alert and aware of whatever may divert you away from Allah: 
2. Remember Allah: 
3.Focus on the main purpose of our lives:

Comment: This misses the topic. While OP mainly asks about braveness your answer addresses fear of God. Which IMO was only mentioned as an example of allowed fear.

Comment: yes , but i think you should know very well that braveness come only (and best solution) with the fear of ALLAH because such a person than not take fear /frighten from any other thing in his life